# The compilation of an array of conditions with numba.jit takes a long time

Tags: python, time, conditional-statements, jit, numba

If I try to compile a function, containing an array of conditions, with numba's jit-compiler, it takes very long. The program looks essentially like

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(a, b):
    valid = [
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0),
        (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    ]

foo(1, 1)
```

where I have excluded everything that will not alter the compilation time significantly. The problem arises if I use more than 20 elements.

```
| elements | time |
-------------------
|    21    | 2.7s |
|    22    | 5.1s |
|    23    |  10s |
|   ...    |  ... |
-------------------
```

Despite that, the function workes well. Does anybody know, why it takes so long, to compile such function with numba? Creating arrays in a similar way with combinations of integers or floats causes no problem.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that is runnable?

Comment: @JoshAdel I changed the example, it is now runnable and simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You may want to report this on the numba [issue tracker](https://github.com/numba/numba), feels like something is going awry in the compiler for it to scale so poorly.
2. You may also consider if you really need a large number of array statements like this and if problem could be more clear refactored.  E.g. instead of array of booleans, could `valid` be a function called as needed?
3. That all said, a workaround in the current version of numba is unrolling the conditions.

For your example:

```
# "codegen"
for i in range(23):
    print(f'    valid[{i}] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)')

@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(a, b):
    valid = np.empty(23, dtype=np.bool_)
    valid[0] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[1] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[2] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[3] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[4] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[5] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[6] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[7] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[8] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[9] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[10] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[11] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[12] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[13] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[14] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[15] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[16] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[17] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[18] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[19] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[20] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[21] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)
    valid[22] = (a - 1 >= 0) and (b - 1 >= 0)

%time foo(1,1)
Wall time: 274 ms
```

Comment: In my original function, all conditions were different and I had to index multiple other arrays with `valid`. It seemed to be the faster and more readable option to use arrays instead of if statements. I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2611) and will update my question if something will change.